# PASCAL procedure won't read value from an external variable

Tags: while-loop, procedure, pascal

Given `a`, `b` and `c`, calculate: `2^a + 2^b + 2^c`.

```pascal
program power;
var a,b,c, r1,r2,r3 :integer;
    
procedure power2(pwr :integer; var result :integer);
var i :integer;
    
begin
    
i := 1;
result := 1;
    
while pwr <= i do
    begin

    result := result * 2;
    i := i + 1;
        
    end;
    
end;
   
   
begin {main}

write('a: ');
readln(a);
write('b: ');
readln(b);
write('c: ');
readln(c);

power2(a, r1);
power2(b, r2);
power2(c, r3);

writeln('power: ', r1 + r2 + r3);
  
end.
```

Why does the program fail to do the `while` loop?

The program prints `3` instead of the sum of `r1`, `r2`, `r3`, independently of the input (a,b,c). How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are incorrect about the while loop comparison, `pwr <= i`.
It should be the other way around.

```
procedure power2(pwr :integer; var result :integer);
var i :integer;
begin    
  i := 1;
  result := 1;    
  while i <= pwr do
    begin    
      result := result * 2;
      i := i + 1;        
    end;    
end;
```